# Loop ggplot for different variables in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I want to loop ggplot and obtain a graph for each variable code is below. I get an error in `aes`

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "b"), A = rnorm(2), B = runif(2), C = rlnorm(2))
for(i in df[,2:ncol(df)]){
 plt<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$ID, y = df[,2:ncol(df)]$i))+
    geom_bar()
  print(plt)
}
```

What is the problem?

I know I could use `facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=ID,y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(~variable)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "b"), A = rnorm(2), B = runif(2), C = rlnorm(2))

for (colname in names(df)[-1]) {
  plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes_string("ID", y = colname)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  print(plt)
}
```

Comment: Note that you can now replace `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` by `geom_col()`.